# Sql query delete all Comments in all Topics which created by an special Username

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables in my sql server 2008

```
TOPIC(idtop,title,usercreated);
COMMENT(idcom,content,idtop,usercom);
```

In my `delete account function`, I have to delete all the topics created by that account and all the comments in each topic.

So first, I have to delete all comments of all topics which created by an special user (`usercreated`) but I really dont know the right syntax to do make that flexible query. Help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't test the query, but you need something like :

```
DELETE FROM COMMENT
WHERE idcom IN (
SELECT idcom FROM COMMENT 
LEFT JOIN TOPIC ON TOPIC.idtop = COMMENT.idtop
WHERE usercreated = 'YOUR_USER'
)
```

and if you also want to delete the topic:

```
DELETE FROM TOPIC WHERE usercreated = 'YOUR_USER'
```